# Running Virtualenv with a custom distlib?

Tags: python, dependencies, virtualenv

I want to do some development on Python's `distlib`, and in the process run the code via `virtualenv` which has distlib as a dependency.

That is, not run the process inside a virtualenv, but run virtualenv's code using a custom dependency. What are the steps I need to go through to achieve this?

It seems to me that normal package management (`pip`) is not possible here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. Thanks for your answer **holdenweb** but this particular situation was a bit more complicated.

I started by cloning the `virtualenv`, `pip` and `distlib` repositories into `~/git-repos/`.

Because of how virtualenv executes pip, changing the Python path is not enough, but also requires modification in `virtualenv/virtualenv.py`

```py
SCRIPT = textwrap.dedent("""
    import sys
    import pkgutil
    import tempfile
    import os

    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, '/home/harald/git-repos/pip')

    import pip
    ...
```

Pip vendorizes distlib, so to run my custom version I created a symlink from pip's standard distlib to my cloned source:

```
~/git-repos/pip/pip/_vendor/distlib -> ~/git-repos/distlib/distlib/
```

Then after creating and activating the environment, I also ran this in the terminal

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=/home/harald/git-repos/pip
```

After this, virtualenv uses my custom code for the creating new virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the easiest way is simply to  modify your Python environment to search another directory where it will find your modified `distlib` before it picks it up from the stdlib? The classic way to do this is by setting your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. No changes required to your Python installation!